# trouble recursively building a binary tree

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

I have this file([the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEeZI.png)): the first word is the illness and the following words are its symptoms
i need to build a binary tree recursively from this data,
however I dont know how to do so. if someone knows - i'd like help

Comment: We can only help you when there is minimum effort from your end. Please post what you have tried.

Comment: @Dana Imagine you're a doctor examining a patient. You ask questions to your patient to determine their symptoms; until you're confident about their illness and can announce it to them. So, first you ask them one question about one symptom. This is the root of the tree. They answer "yes" or "no": these are the two children. Then in each case, you ask a new question. Etc. Until there is only one illness possible (or no way to distinguish between several illnesses that cause the same symptoms); this is a leaf of the tree.

Comment: @Dana If you've played the game [Guess Who?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guess_Who%3F), then this is exactly the same thing, except you're trying to guess an illness.

Comment: See also: [Decision tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.